# Perforce tasks in WebStorm taking forever

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, perforce

I upgraded to WebStorm 2018.1 (Ultimate) and I've been trying to use the perforce integration that's packaged in it. I have an Angular project, and before I upgraded, perforce worked fine and was fast. After the upgrade, every time I try to open a file for editing, the task never completes, it just kind of hangs there.

As an example -- I right-click a .ts file, Perforce -> Edit. The task "Perforce Edit" appears in the bottom right corner as a Background Task and it just hangs there. While that's just sitting there doing nothing, I open a terminal window and `rm -rf node_modules`. Instantly after `node_modules` is deleted, the perforce task is completed and perforce works like a charm.

I have node_modules ignored in P4IGNORE (as an environment variable), so I'm not entirely sure what's going on - anyone else running into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ignore options are set via an environment variable, probably IDE does not know about it (e.g. it was changed while IDE/Toolbox app are running). If it is the case, try to Close the IDE -> Restart the Toolbox app - Start the IDE.

Also, check if adding the node_modules to Settings | Version Control | Ignored files helps.

Comment: Hey! Adding the node_modules directory to the Ignored Files inside the IDE worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So this might help someone else with this problem, but I don't know if it's a solid answer.

I was able to get WebStorm + Perforce to perform somewhat better by basically starting over. I deleted my workspace and WebStorm project and re-configured everything from scratch. For some reason, every file in node_modules is now marked as "unversioned" (even though it's in my p4ignore), but the perforce tasks are running much faster now.